# Zend framework architecture using Data Mapper design pattern

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, design-patterns, datamapper

So I am developing an application using the Data Mapper design pattern but I am having some problems in handling relationships between database tables. I am not sure, and could not find any resource of how should I map my relations with the Data Mapper pattern.

Should I use referenceMap and dependentTables definitions in my DbTable classes or should I go with composition and instantiate a new class when I need it?

For example a blog post and it's author should be something like:

```
$blog->author = findDependentRowset($row)
```

or

```
$author = new Author();
$blog->author = $author->findAuthorById($authorId);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most 'Data Mapper related' way to implement the table relationships in Zend Framework is, as you point out, using `referenceMap` and `dependentTables`.

Depending on other factors (performance needs, complexity of your DB model...) you might want to be a bit less strict with the design pattern and implement the mapping only for the tables, implementing the relationship related queries yourself (by using the `Zend_Select` object provided by `$this->getAdapter()->select()` and some `JOINs`).

Hope that helps,